# redux-form Migration to v6 throwing error in getValues.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I'm attempting to use v6 of redux-form but running into some pretty undescriptive errors. The setup is straight forward, the reducer verbatim from the site:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { reducer as formReducer } from 'redux-form';

export default combineReducers({
  form: formReducer,
});
```

Then, I create a straight forward component without any fields (I get the exact same error when I have fields too).

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';

class LoginForm extends Component {
  render() {
    const { handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        Form
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'login' // a unique name for this form
})(LoginForm);
```

When I navigate to my component, I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'reduce' of undefined
```

The error is pointing to redux-form's getValues.js, and specifically this area of the code:

```
var getValues = function getValues(fields, state) {
  return fields.reduce(function (accumulator, field) {
    getValue(field, state, accumulator);
    return accumulator;
  }, {});
};
```

One idea came from the very bottom of redux-form's [v6 migration page](http://redux-form.com/6.1.0/docs/MigrationGuide.md/) about upgrading react-hot-loader, so I upgraded to 3.X but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `v6` syntax but the version in your `node_modules/redux-form` is `v5`. That `getValues` function no longer exists in `v6`.

```
rm -rf node_modules/redux-form
npm install --save redux-form
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I had to run npm i -S redux-form@6 to make sure I was getting the latest and greatest, otherwise this is the answer!